# How can I set the strings in an array to display: none? JavaScript

Tags: javascript, arrays, string

**Full HTML:**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Seth J. Freeman - WTMP</title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="/HomePage/home.css">
    </head>
    <body>
        <script src="/Resources/jquery-3.1.1.js"></script>
        <script src="/Resources/JQueryPlugins/Ease.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript">
            function codeAddress() {
                // Gathers string content
                var el = document.querySelectorAll(".con-1");

                // Stores text, and prepares it for use
                var myString = el[0].textContent;   

                // Sets a blank array ready to store myString characters at certain positions
                var matchedIndexes = [];

                // Main function, Gathers characters W,T,M,P in myString
                // As long as (I) has a lower value than myStrings length it keeps searching for characters
                for (var i = 0; i < myString.length; i++) {
                    // Gathers characters W T M P
                    if (myString[i] == "W" || myString[i] == "T" || myString[i] == "M" || myString[i] == "P") {
                        matchedIndexes.push(new myMatch(myString[i], i));
                    }
                }

            // Prints to console matchedIndexes array
            console.log(matchedIndexes);

            function myMatch(position, character) {
                // Writes to console the position of the character
                this.position = position;

                // Writes to console the character that was collected
                this.character = character;
            }
         }

            // When the window is loaded call codeAddress function
            window.onload = codeAddress;
    </script>
    <div class="pro-1">
        <div class="con-1 noselect">Welcome To My Playground</div>
        <div class="sod-1 noselect">Stuff Happens Here.</div>
    </div>
</body>
```

**Pointing Towards Specific Problem/Question:**

```
        // Main function, Gathers characters W,T,M,P in myString
        // As long as (I) has a lower value than myStrings length it keeps searching for characters
        for (var i = 0; i < myString.length; i++) {
            // Gathers characters W T M P
                if (myString[i] == "W" || myString[i] == "T" || myString[i] == "M" || myString[i] == "P") {
                    matchedIndexes.push(new myMatch(myString[i], i));
                }
        }
```

**Description:**

What I am trying to do is collect the letters W, T, M, P and separate them from the full string. When they are separated I want to change the display property of only those letters. So far I have gotten the JS code to gather the characters W, T, M, P and print to console there position and what character was collected. Is there a way I could change the display property of those character in the array myString?

Comment: you want find those letter and highlight them, hide everything else?

Comment: Yes. Thats exactly what I am trying to do.

Comment: HI @Seth J. Freeman I  updated more info and code as well, hope it helps =D

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1st call function you should do this `window.onload = codeAddress();` instead of `window.onload = codeAddress;`

2nd I removed `myMatch` function unless you need to save the index.

3rd I used `updatedHtml` to hold the updated html, as you can see if a letter matching, just save it, otherwise wrap it with a `<span class="hid"></span>`. This `hid` class have css `visibility:hidden;` which will hide the content but still take the space. If you want the space to gone as well you could change this to `display: none`.

```js
function codeAddress() {
  // Gathers string content
  var el = $(".con-1");

  // Stores text, and prepares it for use
  var myString = el[0].textContent;
  // hold updated html
  var updatedHtml = [];

  // Main function, Gathers characters W,T,M,P in myString
  // As long as (I) has a lower value than myStrings length it keeps searching for characters
  for (var i = 0; i < myString.length; i++) {
    // Gathers characters W T M P
    if (myString[i] == "W" || myString[i] == "T" || myString[i] == "M" || myString[i] == "P") {
      updatedHtml[i] = myString[i];
    } else {
      updatedHtml[i] = '<span class="hid">' + myString[i] + '</span>';
    }
  }

  el.html(updatedHtml);

}

// When the window is loaded call codeAddress function
window.onload = codeAddress();
```

```css
.hid {
 visibility:hidden;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>


<div class="pro-1">
  <div class="con-1 noselect">Welcome To My Playground</div>
  <div class="sod-1 noselect">Stuff Happens Here.</div>
</div>
```